# Не подтягивается кастомный файл конфигурации ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть проектn, ASP .Net Core в котором с помощью `ConfigurationBuilder` подключается доп файл JSON.

это последний вариант который я использовал:

```
public Startup(
            IWebHostEnvironment env,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration   = configuration;
            UiConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
                .AddJsonFile($"{nameof(UiTemplates)}.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .Build();
        }
```

на локальной машине все норм работает (и в докере и без) а вот когда выливаю на внешний сервер и запускаю (или как демон, или как контейнер) этот файл не подхватывается (в опшинс приходит null).

До этого таких проблем не было, а сейчас не могу понять что поменялось. Наведите на правильный путь, может кто сталкивался.

Comment: Вы сбилдиди конфигурацию и поместили в UIConfiguration. Как оно используется дальше?

Comment: @4per  Предварительно дабавлена к сервисм `services.Configure<UiTemplates>(OptionsConfiguration);` в `Startup` и инжектится по необходимости в определенных классах `IOptions<UiTemplates> uiOpt`